# Angular `12.1.2 error NG8003: No directive found with exportAs 'ngForm'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive

i recently started exploring Angular and wanted to work with forms.

The problem is as the title states. This is my create-theme template.

```
<form  #formData="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="createTheme(formData)">
            <div class="new-theme-title">
                <label for="themeName">Title <span class="red">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" name="themeName" id="themeName" >
                <p class="error">
                    Theme name is required.
                </p>
                <p class="error">
                    Theme name must be at least 5 characters long.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="new-theme-content">
                <label for="postText">Post <span class="red">*</span></label>
                <textarea type="text" name="postText" id="postText" rows="8" class="height" ></textarea>
                <p class="error">
                    The field with your post is required.
                </p>
                <p class="error">
                    Post must be at least 10 characters long.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="new-theme-buttons">
                <button class="cancel">Cancel</button>
                <button class="public">Post</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

What have i tried?

1. - I have imported `import {  NgForm } from '@angular/forms';` into my create-theme component.
2. - I have imported `ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule` into my Theme module that i import into the root.
3. - I have imported `FormsModule` into the root module.

I have no other idea what to do. My test project had a bit simplier form and it was structured the same as it is here. And it works.

Answer (score 3):

After hundreds of posts, i found a solution:

Importing the create-theme component into the App module fixed things. Yet i dont know why.

Comment: That is because if the component is not a part of the module then it doesn't  benefit from the module's imports